# Reference on the authors' willingness to receive public, online feedback on their work

Tags: publications, reference-request, feedback

Is there any research/study/survey that looked at authors' willingness to receive public, online feedback (e.g. public comments on the publisher' website) on the papers they publish?

I am mostly interested in the field of computer science > machine learning / NLP / data mining, and English-speaking venues.

Comment: Can you list one example for "public comments on the publisher's website"? I've never seen that with any of the reputable publishers. Probably the bottleneck here is not the authors, but rather the publisher, because there would be a lot of moderation work.

Comment: @DCTLib Sure, e.g. [PLOS](http://www.plosone.org/static/commentGuidelines). Yes I wonder where the bottleneck is.

Comment: Hmmm, PLOS is not really an example for a publication venue in computer science.

Comment: @DCTLib: Here is another reputable publisher's relevant comment, from [PeerJ](https://peerj.com/benefits/#modern-tools). "And rather than just tack on a blog like commenting system, we've built an entirely new way to interact and provide rich, structured feedback, ask questions, and add media links to any publication."

Comment: @DCTLib NIPS proceedings have public reviews http://papers.nips.cc/book/advances-in-neural-information-processing-systems-27-2014. This is one of the top tier machine learning conferences.

Comment: @SashoNikolov Very interesting! Thanks for sharing the link. The feedback in that case seems to be the official reviews of the papers. Perhaps this is included in what the OP meant, but from my understanding, the OP meant something different when he wrote "public online feedback" - that sounded like everyone can provide feedback, as the official formal reviews are not exactly "online".

Answer (score 1):

Here are two studies that appear to focus on this question:

- [Nariani, Rajiv, and Leila Fernandez. "Open access publishing: what authors want." College & Research Libraries 73.2 (2012): 182-195.](http://crl.acrl.org/content/73/2/182.full.pdf)
- [Mulligan, Adrian, Louise Hall, and Ellen Raphael. "Peer review in a changing world: An international study measuring the attitudes of researchers." Journal of the American society for information science and technology 64.1 (2013): 132-161.](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/asi.22798/full)

Both studies find a lot of ambivalence in current attitudes: in essence, one the one hand, it could be useful, on the other hand [Don't Read The Comments](http://www.themarysue.com/dont-read-the-comments/).