# Mistake in others' papers: how often?

Tags: publications, peer-review, ethics, errors-erratum

Recently I have some experiences in mistakes in the others' papers. One instance was that the formula was simply wrong, and another instance was that the method was numerically impossible to implement. Since both works have been officially published, I am wondering how often do this occur in published papers.

Do people really believe that published works are error-free?

Comment: There are too many distinct questions in this question, most of which are polls (which are not a good fit for this platform). Can you please [edit] your question to reduce it to a single request for general information?

Comment: There are three separate questions:(1) _Do you send emails to the authors to inform them the error?_ (2) _Would this lead to enemies?_ (3) _Do people really believe that published works are error-free?_ Please reduce them to one.

Comment: "Do people really believe that published works are error-free?" - which people? How do we know what people believe? Are you looking for studies with self-reported belief measurements, or what do you expect to hear as an answer? Neither "yes" nor "no" can be an answer here.

Comment: Related: http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/48224/20058 http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/48639/20058 http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/18911/20058