# Should I report two minor mistakes found in an academic paper to the journal editor or authors of the paper?

Tags: publications, collaboration, errors-erratum

I found some minor mistakes in a paper published in a top journal. The mistakes do not affect the results of the paper but may confuse some readers as I was confused at first. I think it is better and more ethical to email the authors and inform them. I have two questions:

1. Should I inform the authors or the journal editor?
2. I need to contact the authors to ask some questions about the paper and request them to provide me the codes of their work if possible. Could informing the authors make them unhappy and prevent them from contributing me? As a whole, could informing the mistake have a negative impact on our future collaboration?

Comment: Related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/48639/68109

Comment: Thanks dear @GoodDeeds. The post you linked can partially answer my first question.

Comment: Search on here, your question 2 has been answered before.

Comment: You have described this as unimportant.  Go do something important instead.